# Field Request - Account has had case within 30 days (T/F)

Tags: custom-field

Our marketing team has requested that I create a field on the Account that will show True if the account has had a case logged within the past 30 days.  They will be using this for some marketing e-mail automation.  I can think of several approaches to this but I'm not sure what would be best.  Could you make some recommendations?

For example, create a checkbox that is read-only to most users.  Set it to default to N (un-checked).  Create a process builder so that when a case is created, it changes the field to Y.  Create a time-based workflow rule to un-check the box after 30 days.

Comment: you really need a field most_recent_case_date__c and a formula to derive the check box. The time-based wf needs a date field to reference

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the checkbox? I ask because you could include the Account in a report selection based on the age of a date just as easily as on the true/false value of a checkbox.That way you can avoid having to update a checkbox later.

So just automate the "Last Case Date" field on Account and run the report off that.

Comment: Our marketing team uses a separate system (autopilotHQ) to send triggered marketing messages.  It cannot use reports, so I have to create fields that the system can read through API.

Comment: Yup. Sorry, what I was meaning was can autopilotHQ query the list of accounts based on something like "Last Case Date > (Today - 30 days)" rather than "Case In Last 30 Days checkbox = True"

Comment: I must be drawing a blank, but I'm not seeing how to do a field for "Last Case Date".  When I look at doing a formula field, it does not show Case as a related list.  When I try creating a roll-up summary field, it does not show Case listed either.

Comment: Yeah, you will have trouble doing it directly like that. I think your original idea of using a process builder process or flow would be better.

Comment: Yup. Just checked and you can do it with a process builder triggered on Case creation and updating a date field in Account to a formula value "NOW()"